# Enthought Canopy emacs keybinding

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, enthought, canopy

Canopy's integrated Ipython terminal allows to use Emacs keybindings, but the integrated code editor won't. This is a problem when switching from one window to the other...
Is there a way to activate Emacs keybindings in "Enthought" Canopy code editor? (I am on OS X)